# Fix terminal shortcuts after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, yakuake

I got used to use Yakuake quake style terminal which uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> for changing window size. These shortcuts have stopped working after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. Right now when I try use one of them I see that terminal inserts `ABDC`. Other terminal emulation applications on my system have the same issue.

Comment: in fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 the keys you mentioned working perfectly.

Comment: Hmm... so where could I mess it up?

Comment: upgrading always have issues like this... can you purge it and install again and see..

Comment: What should I purge when I have the same issue in system terminal?

Comment: for system terminal press Alt+F8 then use side arrows and up & down arrows.

Comment: purge yakuake `sudo apt purge yakuake` `sudo apt autoremove` `reboot` `sudo apt update` `sudo apt install yakuake`

Comment: Yeah, it's like a hack, but still I can't use this shortcuts inside terminal

Comment: Alt+F8 also not working for system terminal?

Comment: Alt+F8 works perfectly because it uses system resizing of window. But when I type Alt+shift+arrow it outputs letters instead treat  it like a kind of shortcut.

Comment: Alt+Shift+Arrow you are talking about yakuake rite, not for system terminal.

Comment: Reinstalling yakuake doesn't help, the problem is somewhere in system wide terminal.

Comment: So that output is correct for system terminal?

Comment: Can you create a new profile in yakuake and see, if not create a new user and see.. recently i have this similar discussion with OP for system terminal who upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04

Comment: I've tried with new user without success

Comment: Oh sorry.. I too don't have any clue mire than this. Thanks.